# How do I fix low FPS while moving bones in pose mode?

Tags: weight-painting, pose-mode, frame-rate

I have low FPS while using pose mode and moving bones. This also happens when I paint in weight painting.

I tried disabling subdivision and placed armature above subdivision but it improved FPS in pose mode by a very little amount. My FPS goes from 25 to 10, is there a way for me to improve my frame rate?

I dont have anything on the scene other than my character that im trying to move in pose mode as seen in the picture.
[image]

Comment: The problem of slow fps playback comes up wvery once in a while, I can only repeatedly say, Blender is not a game engine and not optimized for real-time animation when it involves scenes using a lot of resources. Even scenes where you can work quite smoothly as long as you are on a still frame can be too heavy for quick playback at 24, 25 or 30 fps. The misconception most people have is that the fps setting in Blender is intended to work properly on real-time playback in the viewport. It is not, one indicator is that it's found in the _Output Properties_.

Comment: What you need the fps for is on the one hand to set them correctly to the intended speed if you are directly rendering a video file instead of an image sequence. Also to play that image sequence once it is rendered. On the other hand, physics simulations use the intended playback speed to calculate how to simulate something to make it look realistic when watched at the set fps afterwards. Now to check if a motion looks correct or believable, (good) animation tutorials recommend quick renders from the _View_ menu in _Solid_ or _Wireframe_ mode to just see if the motion is okay at the set fps.

Comment: So, to conclude this: you can try to disable everything unnecessary, try to use a shading mode that is easier to calculate etc. and everything that makes a scene less complex to help with the playback fps, but it is well possible you never reach the set speed and it is not really made for that. Maybe there are things which are using more resources than others in your scene, but to give you tips to what you should most look after specifically we would need your scene.

Comment: Is your model lightweight to begin with? It looks quite smooth from the viewport, high resolution models aren't suited for animation, at least not for real time preview.

Comment: @L0Lock in the picture i have subdivision on level 1 viewport but even when i turn it off it gives me like extra ~2 FPS and i tried making my character as low poly as possible.

Comment: How dense your model is without subsurf?

Comment: @L0Lock around 5800 vertices.

Comment: I think it would help us to have access yo the file and see what's going on by ourselves. Please upload your file on [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to include the download link.

Answer (score -1):

These models still consume resources because the armature modifier is still active.

It is recommended to copy the armature and mesh to a new Blender project, delete other models, and identify which models are causing the resource consumption.
[image]

Comment: Disabling the collections should unload their content and give better performance if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @L0Lock This method works for me; perhaps some other modifiers are affecting Blender's overall performance.